# Given 2 angles find the third angle for all triangles?

Tags: geometry, number-theory, trigonometry, arithmetic, pi

Given 2 angles find the third angle for all  triangles ?

The following 6 trignometric equations describe 6 facts for finding all the angles for all triangles:

$\sin B\cos C + \cos B\sin C=\sin A$

$\sin B\sin C - \cos B\cos C=\cos A$

$\sin A\cos C + \cos A\sin C=\sin B$

$\sin A\sin C - \cos A\cos C=\cos B$

$\sin A\cos B + \cos A\sin B=\sin C$

$\sin A\sin B - \cos A\cos B=\cos C$

And the ratio represents the lenghts of all triangles when the base of the triangles are equal to $1$ unit of lenght, same as hypotenuse for a right angle triangles.

$\frac{\sin A}{\sin C}=a$

$\frac{\sin B}{\sin C}=b$

$\frac{\sin C}{\sin C}=c$

Comment: A + B + C =180 degrees?  Is there a triangle in 2D space this does not work for?

Comment: @Cardinal, Triangles are planar, or 2D, so isn't writing "in 2D space" redundant?

Comment: @UmbQbify-Key20- Likely.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use that
$$A+B+C=\pi\text{ (radians)} = 180 \text{ (degrees)}.$$
This identity is present in any 2D triangle (of course in euclidean geometry).